# Porque este if no me saca del bucle while (Codigo C)

Tags: c

No me sale del bucle la segunda ves que pide el scanf.
Es un programa que pide que solo se haga la seleccion == 1 una vez.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(){
     int x = 0, seleccion = 0;
    while (seleccion != 4){
     scanf ("%d", &seleccion);
     while (seleccion == 1){
         if (x == 1){
printf("Task already done!");
           seleccion = 0;
         }
printf("Task complete!");
         x = 1;
seleccion = 0;
      }
}
    return 0;
    }
```

Me termina saliendo la segunda vez que selecion es 1 ambos mensaje de Task already done y task complete

Comment: No puedo usar el comando de break porque me bajan puntos si lo uso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El original:

```
 while (seleccion == 1){
     if (x == 1) {
       printf("Task already done!");
       seleccion = 0;
       }
     printf("Task complete!");
     x = 1;
     seleccion = 0;
  }
```

Analizando este trozo podemos deducir que el `while` se puede reemplazar con un `if`, ya que `seleccion` es 1, adentro se cambiara inmediatamente por 0.

Más aun, dado que `seleccion` va a ser reemplazado con un `scanf`, puedo eliminar la asignación por completo.

Finalmente, falta un `else` para cuando `x != 1`

Nueva versión:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0, seleccion = 0;
    while (seleccion != 4) {
        scanf("%d", &seleccion);
        if (seleccion == 1) {
            if (x == 1) {
                printf("Task already done!");
            } else {                
                printf("Task complete!");
                x = 1;
                }
            seleccion = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

produce:

```
2
3
1
Task complete!2
3
1
Task already done!
4
```